# Using SQL exists to check a criteria on all databases from a server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, optimization

I'm using VBA to display in an Excel sheet all customers filling some business related criteria.

The server I'm using uses 1 database per customer, I have no way around it, that's what it is. Thoses databases have the same structure though (same tables and same columns by table).

Through coding, I found a way to to this, which works, but I'd like/need to speed it up.

I first get all customers-related databases names through one query, and then execute a query on each result to decide if I should display it or not.

Since SQL treatments are considered to be faster than pretty much everything else, I think I could get my program running faster using a single query, with an "EXISTS" clause inside it, and display all results of this single query.

Here is roughly one thing I tried which might be close to what I need, but doesnt work as it is :

```sql
SELECT name FROM dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE (name LIKE 'DBC%')
AND EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM name.dbo.Purchases WHERE product_category = '012')
```

I just changed some parameters so it's not specific to my company, like what comes after LIKE and the condition after exists, the main point being that I need (do I ? ) to use name in my EXISTS clause to run through all relevant databases.

My problem is that SQL tells me that 'name.dbo.Purchases' is not a valid name (while, when I loop on a query so I can send a SQL query with a real name, say DBC01.dbo.Purchases, it works fine). How can I get name to be considered as what I'm already querying on, as opposed to "name" itself, in a single query ?

I'm not 100% sure that SELECT TRUE works fine but if I need to I'll take a simple field from my table, that's not a primary concern.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem *is* the design here. If you need to dynamically query a database, you need dynamic SQL. `name.dbo.Purchases` doesn't mean `{dbo.sysdatabases.name}.dbo.Purchases` it **literally** means `name.dbo.Purchases`; it's looking for the table `Purchases`, in the schema `dbo`, in a database called **`name`**. (by the way, `dbo.sysdatabases` is a really old object, you should be using `sys.databases`). If you "can't" fix your design, you need to use dynamic SQL and be **VERY** careful you don't introduce a huge wealth of security vulnerabilities. This is why the design is bad.

Comment: As a side note such designs, when you need to query the database dynamically or several at the same time, do *not* lend themselves to performant solutions. If you truly want to optimise the queries, then fixing the design is also the route you want. Likely what you also should be doing is partitioning the data and introducing row level security.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. 
I'm not a fan of this design neither, I don't know why it is this way ; it's on an external  software, widely used in the sector of my company, and with tons of features involving many developpers so that I can't reasonnably build anything comparable on my own.
Security is not really a concern considering queries I use, people who can access this work, and our network. But speed is, so I guess I can't really get a better result.

Comment: But you can get more performance by using dynamic sql. A little searching will show you how to run the same query across many databases and get either one resultset for every database or one resultset per database. Seems like that technique you should know as you will need to use it frequently.

Comment: Thank you, I will indeed investigate on that if it can increase performance, even if not as much as using a better design (which I can't).